# How to set a loop to run continously without getting stuck in infinite loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

I have some code the executes every n minutes and updates some values. I check those values with conditionals and if needed, I call a loop that makes an LED blink. That loop function looks like:

```
def blink_led_constant
    while 1
      #  RPi::GPIO.set_high 18
      #  sleep(1)
      #  RPi::GPIO.set_low 18
      #  sleep(1)
    end
end
```

Basically I want this LED to blink in the background until a certain condition is met. How do I set this to function to run, but also continue past the function call to reiterate my program?

Right now based on how I wrote this, if this function is called it gets stuck infinitely.

Thanks

Comment: What language did you write the code in?

Comment: thanks k.hredos for the tag

Comment: it is written in ruby

Comment: Instead of while 1, why don't you use your condition to loop?

Comment: Try using a Thread to run this code in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a thread to do this.

```
def blink_led_constant
  loop do
    #  RPi::GPIO.set_high 18
    #  sleep(1)
    #  RPi::GPIO.set_low 18
    #  sleep(1)
  end 
end

thread = Thread.new { blink_led_constant }
```

Then you can execute other commands while `blink_led_constant` runs in the background. Change the `loop do` to a `while` if you want it to break once a condition is met. Once the condition is met to stop the led from blinking call `Thread.kill(thread)` or `thread.kill`.

Comment: You may want to specify how the thread should be stopped when condition for blinking LED is no more there

Comment: Ok, I defined the function with condition: loop while $on == true .
and defined blinkthread = Thread.new do
    blink_led_constant
  end

but then when I call Thread::start(blinkthread)
I get an error that says tried to create Proc object without a block

Comment: A few tips, if you want the loop to run while `on` is true, just call `while on`. Second, don't call `Thread::start(blinkthread)`, calling `Thread.new` with a block automatically starts the thread. Third, I'd define the thread as `blinkthread = Thread.new { blink_led_constant }` not `do...end`.

Comment: ok good news, this took care of everything very nicely. Many thanks